# How to resolve error Error: failed to locate view "error"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');

var routes = require('./routes');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/userlist', routes.userlist);
```

But issue is that when I request http://localhost:8081/userlist it gives and error

```
Error: failed to locate view "error"
```

routes/index.js

```
/* GET Userlist page. */
exports.userlist = function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('usercollection');
collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
    res.render('userlist', {
        "userlist" : docs
    });
});
};
```

Express Version : 2.5.8

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't specify view path and view engine, example for ejs templating and directory views

```
var app = express.createServer();
app.set('views', __dirname+'/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```